# jQuery separate dblclick events inside and outside of a div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom

I'm developing a local site for content creation, and I'd like to use javascript's double click functionality.

I'd like to rotate through full screen background images when the user double clicks outside of the divs with names/ids bigwrapper or bigwrapper2.  When the user clicks #bigwrapper or #bigwrapper2, I'd like it to .toggle(); each one to hide/show one or the other.

Here's my **updated code (thanks lordvlad)**:

```
$(function() { 
 $( "#bigwrapper" ).draggable();  
 $( "#bigwrapper2" ).draggable(); 

 var SacramentoBG = ['nightcap.jpg','Tower_Bridge_Sacramento_edit.jpg'], 
     counter =0;            

 $('html').dblclick(function (event) {
    if (event.target.id != "bigwrapper" && event.target.id != "bigwrapper2") {
     counter = (counter+1) % SacramentoBG.length;
     $('html').css('background-image', "url("+SacramentoBG[counter]+")");
 } else {
     $("#bigwrapper").toggle();
     $("#bigwrapper2").toggle();    
 } 
 });
});
```

**UPDATE: The solution below to add 'event' inside the function partially helped, as the backgrounds rotate properly, however the #bigwrappers aren't toggling as intended (the else condition).  See: http://artfuladvection.com/project/NOAA/ndfdGraph/bloom.php Ideas?**

Thanks!

Comment: Check the console and see if you get any errors! Likely there will something interesting to read in there.

Comment: Works fine here... http://jsfiddle.net/SqRQ6/ Can you replicate

Comment: No more console errors after adding 'event' to the function per lordvlad's solution. @PSL: see the url above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complete answer that worked for me was that I needed to stop excluding specific classnames/ids and instead exclude entire element tags. Alternatively, I could just use `if (event.target.TagName == 'BODY') {}`

```
 $('body').dblclick(function (event) {
     if (event.target.tagName != 'DIV' && event.target.tagName != 'IMG' && event.target.tagName != 'TABLE' && event.target.tagName != 'HR' && event.target.tagName != 'SMALL' ) {
       counter = (counter+1) % SacramentoBG.length;
       $('html').css('background-image', "url("+SacramentoBG[counter]+")");
     } else {
       $("#bigwrapper").toggle();
       $("#bigwrapper2").toggle();    
     } 
 });
```

Answer (score 4):

that's because the dblclick function doesn't know about the `event` variable. try this

```
$('html').dblclick(function (event) {
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped fixed the background only cycling, but the #bigwrapper's aren't .toggle()'ing at all. Ideas?  Here's the URL: http://artfuladvection.com/project/NOAA/ndfdGraph/bloom.php